Programmatically generate an array containing `null` values with XPath 3.1
I have a map representing a gaped array; the keys being the indexes of the array:
let $m := map{1: "val1", 2: "val2", 5: "val5", 7: "val7"} return

Now I would like to convert it into a real array, filling up the missing indexes with null:
array {
    ( 1 to max($m => map:keys()) ) ! (
        if ($m => map:contains(.)) then
            $m(.)
        else
            null(())
    )
}

But I get:
["val1", "val2", "val5", "val7"]

Instead of my expected output:
["val1", "val2", null, null, "val5", null, "val7"]


I'm rather confused by your question. There is no such value as "null" in the XDM data model, and there is no function null() as in your example. The XDM equivalent to a JSON null is an empty sequence.
Generating an array that contains non-singleton members (including (), which serialises to JSON null) is tricky in XPath 3.1. One way is to use array:for-each:
array{1 to max(map:keys($m))} 
  => array:for-each($m)

This takes advantage of the fact that array:for-each expects a function, and a map is a function.

My XPath processor allows me to write let $a := [1,null,3] return so I ended-up searching for a null value/function; I found a null() function which I don't understand the purpose, nor know where it comes from. In short, I overlooked the fact that the JSON's null is represented as the empty sequence () in XPath, which makes it tricky to handle.

Ah I see: null in this context means child::null which will return an error if there is no context node, an empty sequence if there is a context node with no children named null, and an element called null if there is such an element. Looks like your code is working by pure luck.

I have no idea where the null() function came from.

lol, what a blunder! Fortunately I've only ever used it for this SO question.

null() is defined in the namespace https://www.jsoniq.org/ , so it's an extension.

If you're using JSONiq then it would be best to say so, because it has many differences from XPath 3.1.

It's likely a remainder of the XPath 2.0 era; the processor implements XPath 3.1 now: JSONiq: JSON APIs (deprecated by XPath 3.1); JSONiq's functions are still around though, like we saw with null()

With [tag:xidel] I have to change array:for-each($m) into array:for-each(function($z){map:get($m,string($z))}). Otherwise I'm getting err:XPTY0004: Expected pvkFunction .... Could this be an implementation bug in Xidel?

It could be a non-conformance, but I would want to see the detail. Whether a non-conformance is a bug depends on whether or not they are claiming to be conformant.

@Reino you're probably using the 0.9.8 version of 2018, which has a few bugs; you can find the current one here: https://nightly.link/benibela/xidel/workflows/main/master

@Fravadona I think you've forgotten it was me who informed you about this in the first place. So the answer is no. I'm aware of the latest developments / discussions.

@Reino My bad, butMichaelKay's solution works with my xidel on macOS and Linux.

I found a possible solution which is to generate a sequence of array(item()?) and use array:join on it:
let $m := map{1: "val1", 2: "val2", 5: "val5", 7: "val7"} return

array:join( (1 to max(map:keys($m))) ! [$m(.)] )

["val1", "val2", null, null, "val5", null, "val7"]

